# Setting django to server media files from google cloud

Tags: python, django, heroku, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to deploy my project in Heroku but the media files (images) are deleted , so someone told me that i need to use a service called "Google cloud", my question is, how to configure my prject to use that service. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use Amazon web services S3 buckets here is a link:
[Link to guide on how to serve media and static files from AWS S3 to a Django app deployed on heroku](https://habr.com/en/post/535054/)